# Extracting data using python

Tags: python

I have a text file like this

```
app galaxy store    Galaxy Store
app text editor Text Editor
app smartthings SmartThings
app samsung pay Samsung Pay
app pdssgentool PdssGenTool
app pdss-sample pdss-sample
app encodertool EncoderTool
app play store  Play Store
app play music  Play Music
app keep notes  Keep Notes
```

where the format is like

```
app(tab)name(tab)name_starting_with_caps
```

From here I only want to extract the `name` part and store it in a list. Can anyone help me how to do that in python. For example `list=[galaxy store, text editor, ...]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`csv.reader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader) with `delimiter='\t'`:

```
import csv

with open('yourfile') as f:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t')
    names = [row[1] for row in csv_reader]
```

Comment: When I am trying this on a large file I am getting `list index out of range` error

Comment: @MohanSingh, that means that some lines are corrupted and don't have equally aligned `\t` delimiter

Comment: okay.. any way to ignore those lines which doesn't have the correct format?

Comment: @MohanSingh, filter rows by valid number of columns with this `names = [row[1] for row in csv_reader if len(row) == 3]`